# How to reate a fixed-width color-ramp with variable values from a text file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently self-studying JavaScript and the project I chose for "learning by doing" is an overhaul of my weather website saakeskus.fi.

For that I have the following problem:
I need to create a legend for each weather map that shows what color means which value. I do have a corresponding textfile for each map. The textfile basically maps values to rgba colors like this:

```
99  255:255:255:0
100 0:50:254:255
200 0:100:254:255
300 0:150:254:255
400 0:200:254:255
500 0:230:240:255
600 0:230:160:255
700 0:230:120:255
800 0:230:80:255
900 0:240:40:255
1000 0:250: 0:255
1100 254:254:0:255
1200 254:225:0:255
1300 254:200:0:255
1400 254:175:0:255
1500 254:150:0:255
1750 230:125:0:255
2000 230:100:0:255
2250 220:75:30:255
2500 200:50:30:255
2750 180:25:30:255
3000 170:0:30:255
3250 180:0:50:255
3500 200:0:100:255
```

What I need to do is load this textfile and create a DIV from it. The width of that DIV must always be the same. It should show the color ramp according to the text file and display the values on the right places below the color ramp. Loading the textfile and creating the DIV with the color ramp is easy. What I'm stuck with is writing the values to the right places and ideally skipping some values if they don't fit (like getting too close to each other). I'd really appreciate some ideas! I have been circling around that problem so much that I probably can't see the forest because of all the trees.

What I currently have is this:

```
function mkLegend(configfile) {
  fetch(configfile)
    .then(function(response) {
      response.text().then(function(text) {
        var result = '<div style="width:250px;height:15px;background:linear-gradient(to right,';
        var lines = text.split("\n");
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length-1; i++) {
          var line=lines[i].split(" ");
          var legValue=line[0];
          var color=line[1].split(":");
          console.log(legValue,color[0],color[1],color[2],color[3]);
          result += "rgba("+color[0]+","+color[1]+","+color[2]+","+color[3]+")";
          if (i < lines.length-2) result += ",";
        }
        result += ');">&nbsp;</div>';
        document.getElementById("legend").innerHTML = result;
      });
    });
}
```

I'm completely stuck on how to tackle the problem of how to write the corresponding values to the right places.

Comment: This is too broad. Show us what you have already, and what you've tried to solve your problem and I'm sure somebody can help with any _specific_ problem.

Comment: @Jamiec: I added my current status. That creates the colorbar, so that works.